# Number of Isomorphic Trees

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory, trees, random-graphs

Given $p = cn^{−1−1/m}(1 + o(1)), m ∈ N, c > 0.$ Prove that the number of components
in $G(n, p)$ isomorphic to a tree on $m + 1$ vertices converges to a $Pois$($\frac{c^m(m+1)^{m−1}}
{(m+1)!}$)random variable.

**What I have tried:**
Okay, I am not 100% sure if what I have tried is accurate but here we go... from Cayley's formula, the number of labelled trees on $k$ vertices is given by $k^{k-2}$.  So let $X_{m+1}$ be the number of labelled trees. $EX_{m+1} = {n \choose m+1}*{m+1}^{m+1-2}* p^{m}$ =${n \choose m+1}*(m+1)^{m-1}* p^{m}$ $\leq$ $\frac{n^{m+1}}{m+1!}$$*(m+1)^{m-1}* p^{m}$ . After this, I applied Stirling's formula and substituted the value of $p$ into the mentioned equation but I am getting a very big messy equation and nothing is cancelling out.  I have been trying to solve it for a long time now but I am not able to. Is my approach correct or I should use some other formula. But I do not see any other formulas to calculate trees except Cayley's one so I applied it. Please help me with this.

Thank you y'all.

Comment: Why do you need Stirling's formula? You have an $(m+1)!$ in the final answer you want, you don't need to estimate $(m+1)!$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Then how will I simply the equation?

Comment: @MishaLavrov And the use of Cayley's is right or should I use some other formula?

Comment: Cayley's formula is correct. Note, however, that $p^{m+1}$ should just be $p^m$: an $(m+1)$-vertex tree only has $m$ edges. Once you have that, substituting $p$ and canceling should give you an expected value of $\frac{c^m(m+1)^{m−1}}
{(m+1)!}$. Next, you should think about what techniques you know to prove Poisson convergence.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I remember studying how independent Bernoulli variables converge in distribution to Poisson distribution.

Comment: The standard result I know is that if you have $\mathbb E[X(X-1)\dots(X-k+1)] \to \lambda^k$ for all constant $k$, then $X$ converges to a Poisson with rate $\lambda$. Here, $X(X-1)\dots(X-k+1)$ would count the number of ordered $k$-tuples of distinct trees in $G$, and you should prove that $G$ has no cycles to limit the kind of $k$-tuples you can get.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yeah I was also thinking this....but then what's the use of taking the expected value of $X_{m+1}$.. Okay, I am confused now.